# Spacing before and after tabular disappears

Tags: tables, line-spacing, setspace

I have some troubles with spacing before and after `tabular` boxes. When my table have only one row, everything is okay.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\doublespacing
Some text.

\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
Some text.\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

Some text.
\end{document}
```

[image: One row]

But when I add new row, spacing before and after table disappears!

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
\hline
Some text.\\ \hline
Some text.\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image: Two rows]

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: usually such a table is inside `center` or `flushleft` environments, which would add some space

Comment: `\doublespace` is the culprit here which leaves enough space when there's a single row in the `tabular`. With multiple rows (2+), the `tabular` still acts like a singular item (like a character) on the line it's put, but it's taller than the expected line height, and is therefore just squeezed in... leaving no vertical space above/below.

Comment: So, what should I do to add the same amount of space, as in first example? `center` and `flushleft` environments add to much space.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like `flushleft` or `center`, you could use `\vspace`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
    \doublespacing
    \noindent I think the best solution is with \texttt{flushleft} (or \texttt{center}) environment:

    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|}
            \hline
            Some text.\\
            \hline
            Some text.\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{flushleft}
    Some text.

    \noindent However, you could use \textbackslash\texttt{vspace*} and set any spacing you want:\vspace*{.1\baselineskip}

    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{|l|}
        \hline
        Some text.\\
        \hline
        Some text.\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}\vspace*{.2\baselineskip}  

    \noindent Some text.
\end{document}
```

[image]